# How can I initialize this ctypes Structure array?

Tags: python, arrays, initialization, structure, ctypes

I have a structure defined using `class` type and I want to initialize `test_arr` like this:

```
from ctypes import *

class ST_DATA(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("test1", c_int),
                ("test2", c_double),
                ("test_arr", c_double*2)]

stmyData = ST_DATA(1, 2, (3, 4))
print(stmyData.test1, stmyData.test2, stmyData.test_arr)
```

Result:

```
1 2.0 <__main__.c_double_Array_2 object at 0x11BB2AD8>
```

I don't understand this situation.  How can I initialize this structure array in Python?

Comment: Convert the `c_double_Array_2` to a `list` to see its content initialized: `print(stmyData.test1, stmyData.test2, list(stmyData.test_arr))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *is* initialized, but the default print representation doesn't reflect the data...just the object's type and address.

It's a good habit to write a debug representation for classes so printing a class instance is more convenient.  In this case, `ctypes` arrays can be converted to lists to see their content:

```py
from ctypes import *

class ST_DATA(Structure):

    _fields_ = [('test1', c_int),
                ('test2', c_double),
                ('test_arr', c_double * 2)]

    # debug representation "magic" method
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'ST_DATA(test1={self.test1}, test2={self.test2}, test_arr={list(self.test_arr)})'

stmyData = ST_DATA(1, 2, (3, 4))
print(stmyData)
```

Output:

```
ST_DATA(test1=1, test2=2.0, test_arr=[3.0, 4.0])
```

See also:

> [`object.__repr__(self)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__)
>
> Called by the `repr()` built-in function to compute the “official” string representation of an object. If at all possible, this should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value (given an appropriate environment). If this is not possible, a string of the form `<...some useful description...>` should be returned. The return value must be a string object. If a class defines `__repr__()` but not `__str__()`, then `__repr__()` is also used when an “informal” string representation of instances of that class is required.
>
> This is typically used for debugging, so it is important that the representation is information-rich and unambiguous.
>
> [`object.__str__(self)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__)
>
> Called by `str(object)` and the built-in functions `format()` and `print()` to compute the “informal” or nicely printable string representation of an object. The return value must be a string object.
>
> This method differs from `object.__repr__()` in that there is no expectation that `__str__()` return a valid Python expression: a more convenient or concise representation can be used.
>
> The default implementation defined by the built-in type `object` calls `object.__repr__()`.

Comment: Thanks to your answer I was able to solve this problem.
It will be really helpful for debugging in the future.